# Make an AJAX call to pass drop down value to the python script

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

I want to pass the selected value from dropdown which contains names of databases and pass it to the python script in the background which connects to the passed database name.
Following is the ajax code that i have written

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
          url : "/form_submit",
          data : $('#databases').val(),
          type : 'POST',
          success : alert("Hi dear count " + $('#databases').val())
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The "databases" is the id of the select tag in HTML. I am writing data :

```
$('#databases').val()
```

to pass the data to the python code.

Following is the python code which should accept the passed value. If i run the below code directly from console, then it returns the result in json format but running it indirectly has not succeeded

```
@app.route("/form_submit/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def connect():
    import json
    dtb = request.select['value']
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","",dtb)
    cursor =  db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM REPORT_SUITE")
    results = cursor.fetchall()   
    json_return_value =[]

    for result in results:
        table_data = {'REPORTSUITE_ID' : result[0], 'REPORTSUITE_NAME' : result[1], 'STAGING_DATABASE' : result[2], 'DWH_DATABASE' : result[3], 'TRANS_TABLE' : result[4]}
        json_return_value.append(table_data)
    print ("hi")
    print json.dumps(json_return_value)
    return json.dumps(json_return_value)
```

I have declared the variable as `dtb = request.select['value']` which should accept the database name passed through AJAX call.
Also i should be able to see the returned data in JSON format in my web browser.
I have looked around and applied many suggested solutions but i still am unable to determine how to pass and catch the passed value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly do you mean by "running it indirectly has not succeeded"? Is there an error message? Do you see the `print("hi")` result in the console when the AJAX request is sent? Have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guidance.

Comment: I am creating a web application using python flask, so when i click the button on html page, it should go to /form_submit/, accept the passed value i.e. database name, connect to it and then return the data in json format to be displayed on the web page and no  it does not print 'hi'. The error message i get is 'Request' object has no attribute 'select'. So it is unable to identify the <select> tag which i have used for drop down.

Comment: Have you used your browser's developer tools to determine the request data passed to flask and/or debugging of javascript?

Comment: I have not done that, but what i could make out was that probably i am not sending and receiving the value correctly.

Comment: I have the issue resolved . i did the following changes                               var data1 = new Object();
    data1.name = $('#databases').val();
    $.ajax({
     url : "form_submit",
     type : 'POST',
     data : data1    and accepted it as follows in python dtb = request.form['name']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `POST` requests, the passed value can be [obtained by](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object)

```
request.form['value']
```

Comment: I found this workaround and also applied it but it says global name 'form' is not defined. I think the code i am writing to call python function and pass the value to it is not correct and also the variable in python program(dtb) which should accept the value is also not correct. Please check my code above which i have pasted.