# How to execute a python function based on a selection of a Drop down list in php?

Tags: php, python, html

I have a dropdown made in html and when I select a value I want a python function to be called. First I try to show a message but nothing happens. I searched methods of writing the php method and I tried them, but nothing successful so far.
Today is my first day on php and html, so please help me ^_^

That is my html page with the dropdown.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>
            <form action="methods.php" method="post">   
                        Selectati planta &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id="myDropdown"> 
                            <option value=""> </option>
                            <option value="planta1">Planta 1</option>
                            <option value="planta2">Planta 2</option>
                        </select>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <button type="submit" value="click" name="submit"> 
                            <font color="blue"> 
                                <b>Ud&#259;</b>
                            </font>
                        </button>       
                    </form>
                    <tr><td> <input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?= $selected_val ?>" ></td></tr>
                </body>
                <?php include "methods.php" ?>
                </html>
    `
```

And this is the php method which I really do not know how it should be written.

```
 ` <?php
    function startWatering()
    {
        $options = array(' ', 'Planta 1', 'Planta 2');
        $selected_key = $_POST['myDropdown'];
        $selected_val = $options[$selected_key];

        if ($selected_val == 'Planta 1') // porneste apa pentru p1
        {   
            echo 'Porneste apa pt planta 1';        
            //exec('sudo python scriptPlanta1.py');
            //header('Location: index.html');
        }
        else if ($selected_val == 'Planta 2') // porneste apa pentru p2
        {
            echo 'Porneste apa pt planta 2';    
            //exec('sudo python scriptPlanta2.py');
            //header('Location: index.html');
        }
        else if ($selected_val == ' ') // se reincarca index.html
        {
            echo 'Nu ati selectat planta';  
            //header('Location: index.html');
        }
    }

                ?>
            `
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32390566/1531971

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is normal that your script do not react when you are selecting something because you include the php page directly to your html page.

Once the page is sent by the server to your computer, the page becomes static as the PHP is only processed on a server side.

You may want to create a asynchronous request to execute your script as it is explain here :[W3 school ajax explain](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

---

EDIT Thank to Ghassen Louhaichi who reminds me the good way!

---

I will explain you this in two ways

The first in raw javascript:

I have just a select and when I change the value:

1. the event onchange will be triggered
2. Call the javascript function
3. Send an asynchronous request to the page action.php
4. The PHP process and answere
5. When the browser get the answere it will alert you your choice

[Example of ajax (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRGs6.jpg)

The html file (sorry I can't use snippet as it does not provide php):
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="myDropdown" onchange="getData()"> 
        <option value=""> </option>
        <option value="planta1">Planta 1</option>
        <option value="planta2">Planta 2</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file (main.js)

```
function getData(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
           alert(this.responseText);
        }
    }

    var dropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");//select the dropdown
    var strUser = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].text; //get the selected value
    console.log(strUser);
    xhttp.open("GET", "action.php?selected=" + strUser);
    xhttp.send();

}
```

PHP file (action.php):

```
<?php
    $selected = "";
    if (isset($_GET['selected']))
         $selected = $_GET['selected'];

    echo $selected;
?>
```

---

The second way is easier to understand as I will use the [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) javascript library to do it faster:

[Picture of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lRan.jpg)

html (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="myDropdown" onchange="execute_script()"> 
        <option value=""> </option>
        <option value="planta1">Planta 1</option>
        <option value="planta2">Planta 2</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript (main.js):

```
function execute_script(){
    //$ is the selector
    //option:selected = selected option
    var selected = $("#myDropdown option:selected").text();

    $.ajax({
        //the link to the page
        url:"action.php",
        //the method
        method: "POST",
        //your data
        data:{"selection":selected},
        success : function(answer, statut){ 
            alert("script ok text:  " + answer);
        }
    });
}
```

php (action.php, for this one I used some of your code):

```
<?php
    $selected = "";
    if (isset($_POST['selection']))
         $selected = $_POST['selection'];
        if ($selected == 'Planta 1') // porneste apa pentru p1
        {   
             echo 'Porneste apa pt planta 1';        
             //exec('sudo python scriptPlanta1.py');
             //header('Location: index.html');
        }
        else if ($selected == 'Planta 2') // porneste apa pentru p2
        {
             echo 'Porneste apa pt planta 2';    
             //exec('sudo python scriptPlanta2.py');
             //header('Location: index.html');
        }
         else if ($selected == ' ') // se reincarca index.html
        {
             echo 'Nu ati selectat planta';  
             //header('Location: index.html');
        }    

    else{
        echo "error script fail";

    }

?>
```

I hope that my edit will help you

Comment: I read what is in the link and I understand what you mean, but I do not know how to write the code with ajax for my dropdown..

Comment: Ok, I will explain this more